# Disabling SIP doesn't allow me to edit "protected" files

Tags: filesystem, sip

I wanted to make a small change to a file in a protected directory, so I went into recovery mode and entered `csrutil disable`. Now rebooted into normal macOS `csrutil status` returns `System Integrity Protection status: disabled.`. Now when I go to make the small change, even after I changed the permissions in the info interface, the warnings are the same as before. My OS is Ventura 13.3 Beta on an M1 Mac. Is it because Apple Silicon, the beta OS or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What file/directory are you attempting to edit. Is it on the “read only” volume?

Comment: I'm trying to add/edit a binary within `/bin` for experimentation purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/bin` is part of the Signed System Volume and can‘t be changed by users any longer, see https://support.apple.com/guide/security/secd698747c9/web for details.

Instead, put your modified binary into any other directory (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`) and make sure this directory is at the beginning of `PATH`.